# how do I calculate when display the control in the scrollbar?

Tags: winapi, windows-10, scrollbar

How do I move the window down only when the control label is out of the client display area? for example, I'm scrolling down using the down key, until label4, the window shall not move. But when it reaches the label5, which isn't entire in the display area, the window must move down, so that the label5 is show. Then same happens with the next label, label6, label7 and so on... I'm struggling to define how I should define that. I thought I could check how many space are there left from current SCROLLINFO.nPos until I reach a page size (SCROLLINFO.nPage) but I didn't find a way to convert a nPos to device units so I could compare those values. An example of behavior of what I'm talking about is the below property grid: you scroll through the controls and the window only move down when necessary, to show the control output of display area, in this case, "DialogResult" and as the below control is also out display area, then it move again, and so on.

The property grid:

[image]

The code that deals with it, note `moveWindow` varaible, which I'm struggling to define.

```
void moveScrollDown(HWND currentControl)
{
    int pos;
    bool moveWindow = false;

    SCROLLINFO si;
    si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_POS | SIF_PAGE;
    if(!GetScrollInfo(hMainWindow, SB_VERT, &si)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(GetWindowRect), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }

 #if 0
    wchar_t buffer[512];
    wsprintf(buffer, L"pos = %d, nPage = %d", si.nPos, si.nPage);
    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"", MB_OK);
#endif

    pos = si.nPos + 1;
    moveWindow = ?? //si.nPos > 0 && (si.nPos % 4) == 0;

    // set new position and range
    si.fMask = SIF_POS;
    si.nPos = pos;
    si.nTrackPos = 0;

    SetScrollInfo(hMainWindow, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
    if(!GetScrollInfo(hMainWindow, SB_VERT, &si)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(GetWindowRect), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }
    pos = si.nPos;

    POINT pt;
    pt.x = 0;
    pt.y = pos - g_scrollY;
    
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hMainWindow);
    if(!hdc) {
        assert(!"couldn't get DC");
    }

    if(!LPtoDP(hdc, &pt, 1)) {
        ReleaseDC(hMainWindow, hdc);
        assert(!"couldn't convert lp to DP");
    }

#if 1
    if(moveWindow && !ScrollWindow(hMainWindow, 0, -pt.y, NULL, NULL)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(ScrollWindow), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }
#endif

    g_scrollY = pos;
realse:
    ReleaseDC(hMainWindow, hdc);
}
```

full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#ifdef UNICODE
#define STRSPLIT wcsrchr
#else
#define STRSPLIT strrchr
#endif

#define __FILENAME__ (STRSPLIT(TEXT(__FILE__), '/') ? STRSPLIT(TEXT(__FILE__), '/') + 1 : TEXT(__FILE__))
#define NAMEOF(s) TEXT(#s)
#define COUNTOF(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void setUpScrollBar(HWND hwnd);
void ErrorExit(LPWSTR lpszFunction, int line, LPWSTR filename);
DWORD ShowLastError(LPWSTR lpszFunction, int line, LPWSTR filename);
void InsertTabItem(HWND tabHwnd, UINT id, LPWSTR text);
void CreateTab(HWND hwnd);
void moveScrollDown(HWND currentControl);

HWND hTab;
HWND label1;
HWND label7;
HWND firstControl;
HWND lastControl;

HWND hMainWindow;
int g_scrollY;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"main window";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

  
    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    hMainWindow =
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"foo",
                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                  100, 100, 330, 180, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            label1 =
            CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 1...",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                50, 10, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 18, NULL, NULL);
            firstControl = label1;
            CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 2...",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                50, 40, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 19, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 3...",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                50, 70, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 19, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 4...",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                50, 100, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 19, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 5...",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                50, 130, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 19, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 6...",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                50, 160, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 19, NULL, NULL);
            label7 =
            CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 7...",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                50, 190, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 19, NULL, NULL);
            lastControl = label7;

            setUpScrollBar(hwnd);
            break;

          case WM_VSCROLL:
            int action = LOWORD(wParam);
            //HWND hScroll = (HWND)lParam;
            int pos = -1;
            if (action == SB_THUMBPOSITION || action == SB_THUMBTRACK) {
                pos = HIWORD(wParam);
            } else if (action == SB_LINEDOWN) {
                pos = g_scrollY + 30;
            } else if (action == SB_LINEUP) {
                pos = g_scrollY - 30;
            } 
            if (pos == -1)
                break;
            
            SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            si.nPos = pos;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);
            pos = si.nPos;
            POINT pt;
            pt.x = 0;
            pt.y = pos - g_scrollY;
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            LPtoDP(hdc, &pt, 1);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, -pt.y, NULL, NULL);
            g_scrollY = pos;
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            switch(wParam)
            {
                 case VK_DOWN:
                    moveScrollDown(NULL);
                 break;
            }
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void moveScrollDown(HWND currentControl)
{
    int pos;
    bool moveWindow = false;

    SCROLLINFO si;
    si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_POS | SIF_PAGE;
    if(!GetScrollInfo(hMainWindow, SB_VERT, &si)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(GetWindowRect), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }

 #if 0
    wchar_t buffer[512];
    wsprintf(buffer, L"pos = %d, nPage = %d", si.nPos, si.nPage);
    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"", MB_OK);
#endif

    pos = si.nPos + 1;
    moveWindow = ?? //si.nPos > 0 && (si.nPos % 4) == 0;

    // set new position and range
    si.fMask = SIF_POS;
    si.nPos = pos;
    si.nTrackPos = 0;

    SetScrollInfo(hMainWindow, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
    if(!GetScrollInfo(hMainWindow, SB_VERT, &si)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(GetWindowRect), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }
    pos = si.nPos;

    POINT pt;
    pt.x = 0;
    pt.y = pos - g_scrollY;
    
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hMainWindow);
    if(!hdc) {
        assert(!"couldn't get DC");
    }

    if(!LPtoDP(hdc, &pt, 1)) {
        ReleaseDC(hMainWindow, hdc);
        assert(!"couldn't convert lp to DP");
    }

#if 1
    if(moveWindow && !ScrollWindow(hMainWindow, 0, -pt.y, NULL, NULL)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(ScrollWindow), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }
#endif

    g_scrollY = pos;
realse:
    ReleaseDC(hMainWindow, hdc);
}

int getDistanceFromTop(HWND c)
{
    RECT rt;
    if(!GetWindowRect(label1, &rt)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(GetWindowRect), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }
    int ht = rt.top;

    memset(&rt, 0, sizeof(RECT));
    if(!GetWindowRect(c, &rt)) {
        ErrorExit(NAMEOF(GetWindowRect), __LINE__, __FILENAME__);
    }

    int lb = rt.bottom;

    return lb - ht;
}

void setUpScrollBar(HWND hwnd)
{
    RECT rc = {0};
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = 220;
    si.nPage = (rc.bottom - rc.top);
    si.nPos = 0;
    si.nTrackPos = 0;

    SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
}

void ErrorExit(LPWSTR lpszFunction, int line, LPWSTR filename)
{
    DWORD dw = ShowLastError(lpszFunction, line, filename);
    ExitProcess(dw);
}

DWORD ShowLastError(LPWSTR lpszFunction, int line, LPWSTR filename)
{
    #define MAX_DIGITS 16

    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL
    );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID) LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
            (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) +
            lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40 +
            (line > 0 ? MAX_DIGITS : 0) +
            (filename != NULL ? lstrlen(filename) : 0)) *
            sizeof(TCHAR)
    );
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
                    LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
                    TEXT("%s failed with %d: %s"),
                    lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf
    );
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    return dw;
}
```

Comment: I think there is no simple method or API to calculate the length. In Win32 controls, complex implementations are needed to complete this function. Perhaps you need to compare the coordinates of the control at the end of each display area with the coordinates of the main window. If the coordinates of the main window are less than The control coordinates move the scroll bar.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT I thought something like this hence I wrote that `getDistanceFromTop()` function. The goal was check how far is the control from the first control in the main window, if it's greater than the scrollbar's page size, then I would move the window. But I couldn't make it work, even if the control if below than the scrollbar's page, the returned distance isn't greater than the scrollbar's page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need similar calculations:

```
RECT rc;
GetWindowRect(hMainWindow, &rc);
int bm = rc.bottom;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {    //label[0] - label[6] are your static controls.
    GetWindowRect(label[i], &rc);
    if (rc.bottom > bm&& rc.top <= bm) {
        //do some calculate
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: out this, I got some idea how I could write the `moveWIndow` and `offby` routines so when `moveWindow()` is true, I call `offby()` to know how off is that control from the visisble area than update the scrollbar nPos to it but it's working only once. If I press the key down key in this control we just show, it didn't update anything. the "current control" is the control where the key up was sent from, each control is subclassied. Here's the routines sofar https://pastebin.com/mu0MX43n

Comment: I think you need debug to test whether the calculation meets your expected results. The height of the control and the distance between the controls will affect the result of `GetWindowRect`, which may cause problems in your code.

Comment: But the algorithm idea is right or are there some better approach to this?

Comment: I think the idea of the algorithm is correct, and there may be a better way, but I can only give the solution at present.